# How to Laplace transform the $\sin$ and handle $\Im(\cdot)$ inside integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform

For a function $\sin(at)$, I get the exponential order $\gamma = 0$ because the function is limited through $|\cdot|\leq 1.$ I try to calculate the following:
$$\mathcal{L}\{\sin(at)\}(s)$$
where $s$ is my complex frequency in the newly calculated transform. My Idea is the following: 
$$\mathcal{L}\{\sin(at)\}(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin(at)\;\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\Im\left ( e^{iat} \right )\;\mathrm{d}t.$$

$\Im$ is the imaginary part of my term and $\Re$ would return the real part. But because I have to assume that $s$ has the form $$s=\sigma + i\omega,$$
I cannot combine those integrals as easy as I thought.
How to solve this particular problem and handle the $\Im(\cdot)$ or $\Re(\cdot)$ in such cases in general?

Comment: I see that someone changed my $Im, Re$ to $\Im,\Re$ but I think both is legit as one can see on Wikipedia or university scripts etc. But thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to do the same.

We have, $$L[e^{bt}] =\frac1{s-b} $$ Set, $b=ia$, it gives: $$L[e^{iat}] =\frac1{s-ia} =\frac{s+ia} {s^2+a^2} = L[\cos at +i\sin at] $$

Equating the real and imaginary parts on both sides, we have: $$L[\sin at] =\frac{a} {s^2+a^2}$$ and $$L[\cos at] =\frac{s} {s^2+a^2}$$

Comment: Okay, thanks, great!

But would it work via my way as well? For more complex forms of a similar kind containing $Im, Re$?

Comment: Yes, what you do is just compute the entire integral and then take the imaginary part of it. That's all.

Comment: But this does only work if my function is part of sum that represents a much easier function to integrate, right?

Comment: Your integral can be written as:$$I =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-St} \Im(e^{iat}) \, dt$$ $$=\Im(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{iat-st} \, dt) $$ $$=\Im(-\frac1{ia-s}) =\Im(\frac{s+ia} {s^2+a^2})$$ $$=\frac{a} {s^2+a^2}$$

Comment: Okay, that cannot be true because $s$ may be equal to $\sigma + i\omega$ and so $s\neq\Im (s)$ for $s\neq\sigma$.